# Diagnosis of slow brake leak

Tags: brakes, leak, acura, integra

I have determined the general source of a brake fluid leak on my 1994 acura integra but am unsure which component has failed causing the leak.

After tracing all of the lines in the car and examining the master cylinder i found the source of the leak to be the driver's side rear brake caliper or brake hose.  Both components are soaking wet with brake fluid.

Is there a way to determine which of the two is the causing this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to check is to jack the wheel up (put it on a jackstand), take the wheel off, clean off the affected areas with brake cleaner, then have a second person push on the brake pedal hard to observe where the leak is coming from.

If the fluid is up onto the brake line, I'd suggest this is actually the source of your leak. It could also be where the line attaches to the caliper. There is usually a banjo bolt which has two copper (or brass) washers on them. While not a tendency, these washers have been known to leak. The caliper itself will usually only leak around the piston area, if at all ... that is unless someone left the bleeder screw open.

Comment: The bleeder screw is not open that was the first thing I had checked.  I'm considering just replacing both to not have to worry about it

Comment: If you are going that approach, consider just changing out the hose first and ensure you have fresh washers on it as described. It will be a lot cheaper in the long run if you don't have to replace the caliper.

Comment: That is probably a good idea to avoid having to replace the caliper which is significantly more expensive

Comment: A rusty ferrule on the end of the rubber hose can be a source of leaks.

Comment: If you try this, wear goggles - just in case fluid squirts out under pressure...

Comment: @NickC Sound advice, I'm not trying to go blind. I know brake fluid is some nasty stuff.

Comment: If you do end up needing to replace the caliper...replace the other side as well. If one side is leaking from wear the other is close behind. A 'loaded pair' of calipers is usually just a bit more than 1 caliper and a set of pads.